# Webhook CheckMK Notification Not Working, How Do I find verbose logs for this notification?

Tags: python, check-mk

I am aware of the notify.log located at /opt/omd/sites/servername/var/log/notify.log however this provides very little information about what is actually happening when my custom python script runs. I am using the python script below but it is not triggering the webhook as expected.

Does anyone know of a better logging file or another way to troubleshoot this? I have confirmed that the native teams webhook is working fine so it shouldn't be a networking issue preventing the webhook from going out.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Jenkins

import os
import requests
import sys

COLORS = {
"CRITICAL": "#EE0000",
"DOWN": "#EE0000",
"WARNING": "#FFDD00",
"OK": "#00CC00",
"UP": "#00CC00",
"UNKNOWN": "#CCCCCC",
"UNREACHABLE": "#CCCCCC",
}


def teams_msg(context):
facts = []

type = context.get("WHAT", None)

if not type:
    sys.stderr.write("Unable to determine notification type")
    sys.exit(2)

state = context.get("{type}STATE".format(type=type), "UNKNOWN")
color = COLORS.get(state)
subtitle = "{type} Notification".format(type=type.capitalize())
output = context.get("{type}OUTPUT".format(type=type))

if type == "SERVICE":
    facts.append({"name": "Service:", "value": context.get("SERVICEDESC")})

facts.extend(
    [
        {"name": "Host:", "value": context.get("HOSTNAME")},
        {"name": "State:", "value": state},
        {"name": "Timestamp:", "value": context.get("LONGDATETIME")},
    ]
)

facts = list(filter(lambda x: x["value"], facts))

return {
    "@type": "MessageCard",
    "@context": "https://schema.org/extensions",
    "summary": subtitle,
    "themeColor": color,
    "sections": [
        {
            "activityTitle": "CheckMK",
            "activitySubtitle": subtitle,
            "activityImage": "https://checkmk.com/favicon-32x32.png",
            "facts": facts,
            "text": output
        }
    ]
}


def collect_context():
return {
    var[7:]: value
    for (var, value) in os.environ.items()
    if var.startswith("NOTIFY_")
}


def post_request(message_constructor, success_code=200):
context = collect_context()

url = context.get("PARAMETER_1")
r = requests.post(url=url, json=message_constructor(context))

if r.status_code == success_code:
    sys.exit(0)
else:
    sys.stderr.write(
        "Failed to send notification. Status: %i, Response: %s\n"
        % (r.status_code, r.text)
    )
    sys.exit(2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
post_request(teams_msg)
```

Comment: You can increase the logging verbosity in Checkmk itself. That should provide more ourput. I cannot read your code, but I assume you already built in some logging there?